# sending sms from iphone with http links

Tags: ios, sms

Is there anything special I need to do when sending http links as part of sms message from IOS programmatically?
When I send a message that includes a link http://echowaves.com/mobile?token=123123 the first part of the link shows as a link, but everything after ? (including ?) shows as a plain text. So when the link is clicked the token parameter is not included. I thought, maybe there is a problem with SMS client that does not know how to parse the links, but the same exact behavior is experienced in IOS as well as on Android. Also, when I try to send the SMS message and manually type the link with parameter -- it get's interpreted properly when received.

Comment: here is one more finding: if I'm composing an SMS message with stringWithFormat -- the link does not show properly when the message arrives. If I hardcode the dynamic token into the @ string -- it shows properly. It's hard to believe, but seems that stringWithFormat does something nasty to the string.

Answer (score 0):

Wacky,
just retyped the whole string manually by hand -- and it works. Perhaps some special character or encoding was getting on a way after copy paste string around.